# Conditional read more adjustment

Tags: functions, conditional-tags

I get the read more link like this

```
<?php the_content("Read More"); ?>
```

I want on the Homepage a different text than on an archive pages.

I can change the text for all read more links in functions.php like this

```
add_filter( 'the_content_more_link', 'modify_read_more_link' );
function modify_read_more_link() {
return '<a class="more-link" href="' . get_permalink() . '">Your Read More Link Text</a>';
}
```

but that will change all read more links.

A conditional tag like is_home() in functions.php also doesn't work.

What could do the job?

Comment: Did you try `is_front_page()` ?

Comment: Yes and nothing else works because conditional tags inside the functions.php won't work in this case.

Comment: Any change you're using `query_posts` that could be messing around with the global main query ?

Comment: In this loop only $args = array( 'post__not_in' => get_option( 'sticky_posts' ), 'posts_per_page' => 1); . There are some other loops on the page, but I don't know if that matters

Answer (score 1):

It was simpler than I thought. This has solved it.

```
<?php
add_filter('the_content_more_link', 'modify_read_more_link');
function modify_read_more_link()
{
    return '<a class="more-link" href="' . get_permalink() . '">Your Read More Link Text</a>';
}
the_content("Read More");
?>
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer ;-)